# Postgres tables seem partially dropped

Tags: postgresql, ddl, pgadmin

Today I had a problem with my Postgres DB and am having a hard time rationalizing what could have happened. I'm looking for technical details on how the apparent 'partially dropped' state could have happened. I was under the impression that dropping a table was atomic.

**Systems:** I have Postgres 9.4 installed on RHEL 6.5 which I access using the pgAdmin III GUI from Windows 7. I also have a non-db RHEL 6.5 machine from which I can use psql.

**Set-up:** I tried to delete a few small tables (~1k rows each) at once using the GUI (by multi-selecting the tables, right-click, drop) and pgAdmin crashed. All but two of the tables were deleted successfully.

**Issue:** When I try to get table information for either of the two tables that weren't deleted, pgAdmin hangs and does not recover. When I run a 'drop table' or 'select' query from pgAdmin I get an error that says that the table does not exist (for either table). The tables appear when I run \dt from psql and I can see details about the tables in the information_schema.columns table. There is no database activity in the pg_stat_activity table.

**Resolution:** I ran 'drop table' on one of the tables from psql and got "ERROR: table "my_table_name" does not exist". It took about 30 seconds to get the error and for tables of this size I'd expect a 'drop table' query to return within just a few seconds if it was actually dropping the table. This makes me think that it was doing some sort of clean-up in addition to trying to drop the table. From \dt and information_schema, the table appears to have been deleted. Now pgAdmin doesn't hang when I get table stats on the other table that was meant to be deleted.

It seems like the tables were 'partially dropped' which seems like something an ACID compliant db couldn't do. I expected that it had something to do with an open transaction but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Anything interesting show up in the server log during this whole ordeal?

Comment: I've asked my admin for the logs but it'll require approval so I probably won't get them this week.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the logs but I was told there was nothing unusual in them. I'm not sure if there's anything else to do on this question without more data.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the drop that pgAdmin was attempting was inside of a transaction, and when pgAdmin crashed that would have left the transaction open in the Postgres backend. It can take quite a while for the OS to notice the connection is no longer valid and close the socket, which is the cue for Postgres to shut down that backend. Shutting down with an open transaction will roll that transaction back.

The reason you didn't see this effect with \dt is the query against the catalog still sees the table as being present, because the transaction hasn't committed yet.

The `DROP TABLE` command took forever because the open transaction still held an exclusive lock on the table. Once the transaction was terminated that lock was released, and the second drop could proceed.

Comment: Although the psql DROP TABLE took a good 30s, the message was that it failed while the absence of the table afterwards suggests that it succeeded. Furthermore, if there was an open transaction wouldn't it have shown up in the pg_stat_activity table?